# search results tableview not displaying the contents of its cells even while filtering of the contents of the table is working fine

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

i have a viewcontroller containing multiple tableviews managed by the same viewcontroller.i added search to one of the tableviews... i have added the searchbar amd searchisplaycontroller and wired up the outlets for searchdelegate,searchdatasource,searchbar.etc...
[image: image showing the views in vc in storyboard]

i have the code for filtering the contents of the table working correctly...

below is the code inside the cellforrowatindexpath method

```
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"search";

        SearchFieldsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[SearchFieldsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }
        NSDictionary *field=nil;


        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

            field =  _searchfieldsArray[indexPath.row];
        }
        else{
             field = _fieldsArray[indexPath.row];
        }


        cell.titleLabel.text=field[@"a"];
        cell.subtitleLabel.text=field[@"b"];
        cell.detailLabel.text=field[@"c"];



        cell.flagImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_flag.png"];
         return cell;
```

but its not displaying the contents of the tableview... even the height of the tableviewcell is set and during the runtime... if i give printobject like po cell.titlelabel.text in the debug console it gives result like

```
<UILabel: 0xc15d500; frame = (70 0; 241 21); text = 'result'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xc15d5b0>>
```

i further found out that the line of code 
 `SearchFieldsCell *cell=[tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];`

is perfectly working ie loading the prototype cells from the storyboard but the line

```
if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[SearchFieldsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            }
```

is returning empty white cells somehow its not loading from the prototype cells from the storyboard... how can this happen...?? anyone please help...

Comment: Are you using Prototype Cell or Custom cell as you mentioned - SearchFieldsCell ??

Comment: prototype cell in storyboard... the custom class for it is SearchFieldsCell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know its not done this way...but after so many different ways the solution was to create a custom xib file and make the uisearchresultscontrollers tableview to register this nib file .it worked

```
 [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SearchFieldsCell"
                                                  bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
            forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Search"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to type cast cell with custom cell class. So it will initialize & not be null value.

```
SearchFieldsCell *cell = (SearchFieldsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: simpleTableIdentifier];
```

Hopefully, it will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: hi i tried this but didnt work...somehow only in the searchtable of searchdisplaycontroller the cells are becoming empty